# Jassor slider play from slide0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a one page scrolling website. I am using Jassor slider with 3-4 slides auto-playing, i I want to somehow make the `href="#home"` or `href="#"` which takes to top of the page where the slider is on some random autoplaying slide. is

Is there any way i I can reset to first slide when the page scrolls to #home?

currently my slider code looks like this

```
     jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
              [{b:0.0,d:600.0,y:-290.0,e:{y:27.0}}],
              [{b:0.0,d:1000.0,y:185.0},{b:1000.0,d:500.0,o:-1.0},{b:1500.0,d:500.0,o:1.0},{b:2000.0,d:1500.0,r:360.0},{b:3500.0,d:1000.0,rX:30.0},{b:4500.0,d:500.0,rX:-30.0},{b:5000.0,d:1000.0,rY:30.0},{b:6000.0,d:500.0,rY:-30.0},{b:6500.0,d:500.0,sX:1.0},{b:7000.0,d:500.0,sX:-1.0},{b:7500.0,d:500.0,sY:1.0},{b:8000.0,d:500.0,sY:-1.0},{b:8500.0,d:500.0,kX:30.0},{b:9000.0,d:500.0,kX:-30.0},{b:9500.0,d:500.0,kY:30.0},{b:10000.0,d:500.0,kY:-30.0},{b:10500.0,d:500.0,c:{x:87.50,t:-87.50}},{b:11000.0,d:500.0,c:{x:-87.50,t:87.50}}]
            ];

            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $Idle: 2000,
              $FillMode: 2,
              $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
              }
            };

            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 600);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize",  $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);


            //responsive code end
        };
function SliderParkEventHandler {
                    jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(0);
}
```

trying to call the function SlideParkEventHandler from a link `<a href="#home"  onclick="return SliderParkEventHandler();">>Home</a>`

my idea is make an api call `$PlayTo(0)`

you can have a look at the full code at [blackgoldconferences.com](http://blackgoldconferences.com)

Comment: Please give the link of the slide you are using?

Comment: jssor_slider1 is not a global variable i think...you can define that variable outside the functions...

Comment: var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options); to jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options); and outside all functions; var jssor_1_slider = '';

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing the `jssor_1_slider` inside `jssor_1_slider_init` so the scope will be local and it cannot be called from out side.

Declare the variable in global scope so that you have access to the instance using which you can change the slides

```
var jssor_1_slider;

jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

    var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
        [{b:0.0,d:600.0,y:-290.0,e:{y:27.0}}],
        [{b:0.0,d:1000.0,y:185.0},{b:1000.0,d:500.0,o:-1.0},{b:1500.0,d:500.0,o:1.0},{b:2000.0,d:1500.0,r:360.0},{b:3500.0,d:1000.0,rX:30.0},{b:4500.0,d:500.0,rX:-30.0},{b:5000.0,d:1000.0,rY:30.0},{b:6000.0,d:500.0,rY:-30.0},{b:6500.0,d:500.0,sX:1.0},{b:7000.0,d:500.0,sX:-1.0},{b:7500.0,d:500.0,sY:1.0},{b:8000.0,d:500.0,sY:-1.0},{b:8500.0,d:500.0,kX:30.0},{b:9000.0,d:500.0,kX:-30.0},{b:9500.0,d:500.0,kY:30.0},{b:10000.0,d:500.0,kY:-30.0},{b:10500.0,d:500.0,c:{x:87.50,t:-87.50}},{b:11000.0,d:500.0,c:{x:-87.50,t:87.50}}]
    ];

    var jssor_1_options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $Idle: 2000,
        $FillMode: 2,
        $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
        },
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
        },
        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
        }
    };

    jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (refSize) {
            refSize = Math.min(refSize, 600);
            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
    }
    ScaleSlider();
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize",  $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);


    //responsive code end
};
function SliderParkEventHandler {
    jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(0);
}
```

Comment: ty, it seems an improvement now. but i am getting ReferenceError: SliderParkEventHandler is not defined

Comment: may be you are defining that method inside `$(document).ready`. move the variable declaration and method definition out of that